# When is removing salutations a step too far?

Tags: discussion, editing

I know that "Hi", "Thanks", and so on should be edited out of questions and answers. I've done it thousands of times. There's [a new, good answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/51243/46) on a question I answered and it starts and ends with flowery (and I think significant) greetings.

> Peace be upon you, and Allah's mercy, and His blessing.
>
> May Allah make it easy for you and your family, and keep you safe in your travels.

Normally I remove these sorts of things. But this question is specifically about religious practices while traveling (in this case, avoiding an animal the OP believes will make him unclean) and that is making me feel I shouldn't remove them.

Am I being silly?
 Would you remove them?

Comment: I just removed the salutations from the linked posts.

Answer (score 14):

> Peace be upon you, and Allah's mercy, and His blessing.

Is the Islamic way of saluting people in any occasion, which is a translation to:

> السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته

That's basically our way of saying `hi`, and since deleting a `hi` is fine, or any other salutation, then it will be totally fine to delete this as well.

Finally, I am a Muslim and I see no harm nor insult in deleting the Islamic salutation from posts. Why would only keep the Islamic salutation? if I noticed it earlier I would have done that myself. Good call JoErNanO.

Answer (score 13):

Personally I would remove them because they add nothing valuable to the answer. Mine is a qualitative judgement alone, I have nothing against blessings and thank you notes.

Addendum: I just removed the salutations from the linked posts.